# Qtspim memory and registers cleared error

Tags: qtspim

I accidentally touched qtspim so the error 'memory and register cleared' suddenly appears and it doesn't work.Even if I turn off the computer or re-install the program, I keep getting the same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To restore the memory and the registers to regain the graphical user interface go to 'Window' in the menu bar and select restore default settings

[image: Restore default settings option]

This should return the default view and remove the error message. This has been tested on a Mac.